# Rails Deployment - Run assets:precompile once per deployed environment or only once per build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

TL;DR: Running assets:precompile injects production asset hosts into the generated assets for non-prod environments.

Background: The current way we deploy our Rails app is that the CI server deploys each successful build to the integration env as a tarball. And this tarball keeps getting promoted all the way to the prod env. But even before we tar the app to promote to different environments, we run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Once this command is run before tarring, we ended up with the compiled assets as a part of the tarball and this saves deployment time for individual environments (The precompile is sloow).

Problem:
This arrangement worked fine until we introduced the asset_host property in the production environment. Because the assets:precompile is run in Production env by default, and the sass files refer to image assets using the image-url tag, the asset host started getting picked up by the precompile and the generated assets started having direct URL references to the production asset_host's servers. Obviously this is not acceptable.

Searching on the internet led to this [Github Issue](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/93) which is a pretty close description of  the problem I'm having. Seeing the reaction of the gem maintainers, it seems like running assets:precompile once for ALL environments instead of once PER environment seems like a bad idea. But given slow precompile times, it seems to be the only way our for us.

So how are other Rails deployments dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was solving very similar problem. Our solution was to run the pre-compilation for every individual environment - in our case that were staging and production environments. The reason was the same - different asset hosts.

If you can, run the pre-compilation only in environments where it is necessary and where assets are really needed.

We are using Capistrano to do deployments along with the `capistrano-ext` gem. This allows us to specify different stages and to each stage settings and methods that are specific for the stage (or environments if stage == environment).

Answer (score 0):

check public/assets/manifest.yml into source control